# How to make a background image similar to scrolling wallpaper in Android?

Tags: android, ios, image, scroll, wallpaper

I use a navigation-based iOS application. I want to make a background similar to desktop wallpaper in Android.
So when I go to another View the current View and it's content goes outside of the screen but the background image slightly moves only.
See a [sample screenshot here](http://www.oliverwutscher.com/DeHD1.jpg).

Comment: Hi, did you already found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the base subview set to the size of the background wallpaper (ie larger than the screens width) and start with it left aligned. Then have a paged `UIScrollView` on top of that. When the user scrolls the `UIScrollview`, hook into the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method 
`- scrollViewDidScroll:` and pass it through the the base subview, telling it to animate in accordance.

This shouldn't be too hard but you'll probably want to tweak it a bit to get the feel you want.Try playing about with the various delegate methods in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to determine the best time to start the animation.